# What is the Python equivalent of StringEntity in Java?

Tags: java, python, json, python-2.7

I have the following class in Java:

```
class JsonEntity extends StringEntity {
    private final String string;

    public JsonEntity(String string, Charset charset) {
        super(string, ContentType.create(ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.getMimeType(), charset));
        this.string = string
}
```

I have no clue how to implement the above code in Python 2.7. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don' know if I exactly get your need, however if you need to save as JSON with a particular charset in python you can do something like this:

```
import json 
json_string = json.dumps("your string even with wierd symbols", ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')
```

NB: you can change utf8 with other charsets.

**EDIT:**
Anyway if you need to extend something to actually implement your json reader/writer you can extend JSONEncoder:
https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder

Comment: This is actually not what I need, but thanks for the info.